# Replacing when a word is in another word but with special circumstances

Tags: python, parsing, text

My program replaces tokens with values when they are in a file. When reading in a certain line it gets stuck here is an example:
`1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 Token100.1 1.1.1.1.1.1.1Token100a`

The two tokens in the example are Token100 and Token100a. I need a way to only replace Token100 with its data and not replace Token100a with Token100's data with an a afterwards. I can't look for spaces before and after because sometimes they are in the middle of lines. Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#index-20) to ensure that the following character is not an `"a"`:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = '1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 Token100.1 1.1.1.1.1.1.1Token100a'
>>> re.sub(r'Token100(?!a)', 'data', test)
'1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 data.1 1.1.1.1.1.1.1Token100a'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
line = "1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 Token100.1 1.1.1.1.1.1.1Token100a"

match = re.sub("Token100a", "data", line)
print(match)
```

Outputs:

```
 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1 Token100.1 1.1.1.1.1.1.1data
```

More about regex here:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp